# Symfony Cache TagAwareAdapter problem with saving and then getting cacheItem

Tags: symfony, caching

Symfony's FilesystemTagAwareAdapter() lets me get, assign a value to, and save a cacheItem, and then retrieve the saved item with another get. But if I also tag the new item before saving, I cannot retrieve the saved item with another get.

1. when I run the following:

```
$this->cache = new \Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\FilesystemTagAwareAdapter();
$thingItem = $this->cache->getItem('thing');
$thingItem->set('thingValue');
// $thingItem->tag('msc');
$this->cache->save($thingItem);
$retrieved = $this->cache->getItem('thing')->get();
```

The value of $retrieved is "thingValue".

2. If I uncomment the "$thingItem->tag('msc');" line and run the code again, the value of $retrieved is null.

I would expect the value of "$retrieved" to be "thingValue" in both cases.

Can anyone explain the inconsistent behavior?

Edit:
This is on php 8.1 and windows 10.

The inconsistent behavior occurs in a phpunit TestCase test in a Symfony project I am working on.

I find that the inconsistent behavior does not occur in a function test using Symfony's KernetTestCase with $this->cache = static::getContainer()->get('cache.app.taggable');

Comment: I cannot reproduce your bug. Btw, you mix `$this->cache` and `$cache`. Do you mistakenly have two instances of the cache?

Comment: I removed all `this->` from the code and tried to reproduce the error, failed, I got "thingValue" - also with the `->tag()` call. the comment by simon.ro is on point, I guess ;o)

Comment: I have set every cache reference to $this->cache and added reference to php version and o/s. I'm wondering if Windows is blocking something cache tries to do in the default tmp directory when adding a tag?

Comment: the tagging by default works via symlinks in an extra tag directory. if the OS doesn't allow symlinks, the cache entry will be removed: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6.3/src/Symfony/Component/Cache/Adapter/FilesystemTagAwareAdapter.php#L149-L150

Comment: Thank you simon.ro and Jakumi. I have added a note that the inconsistency occurs when the code is run in a unit test but does does not occur in a functional test. So I guess my "fix" is to test the service in which I use the cache in a functional test. I still wonder why it does not work in the unit test, though.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

It appears that the cache.app.taggable that symfony creates in a **Windows** environment is not a FilesystemTagAwareAdapter. It is a TagAwareAdapter wrapped around a TraceableAdapter wrapped around a FilesystemAdapter().

So if I create my cache this way:

```
$this->cache = new TagAwareAdapter(new TraceableAdapter(new FilesystemAdapter());
```

The code works as expected in a phpunit test!